# Issue with fragment OptionsMenu when recall fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new LayOutOne()).commit();
    }

}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.settings:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PrefFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**PrefFragmentList extends PreferenceFragment**

```
public class PrefFragmentList extends PreferenceFragment {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

}
```

**PrefFragment extends Fragment**

```
public class PrefFragment extends Fragment {
private View v;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_settings, null);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return  v;
}
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    menu.findItem(R.id.settings).setVisible(true).setEnabled(false).setChecked(true).setChecked(true);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

PROBLEM:

MainActivity call PrefFragment from OptionMenu , when i go back to MainActivity and re-call PrefFragment, the application crash.

**LOGCAT:**

```
 11-27 12:12:50.857 1387-1387/xx.xxx.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 228K, 3% free 9211K/9476K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
11-27 12:13:02.584 1387-1387/xx.xxxx.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-27 12:13:02.584 1387-1387/xx.xxxx.myapplication W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4178b700)
11-27 12:13:02.592 1387-1387/xx.xxxx.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at xx.xxx.myapplication.PrefActivity.onCreateView(PrefActivity.java:23)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f0e0052, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for xx.xxxxx.myapplication.PrefFragment
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4751)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at xxx.xxxx.myapplication.PrefFragment.onCreateView(PrefFragment.java:23) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If there is a crash then there will be some exception log (Logcat), please post it.

Comment: From the logcat: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f0e0052, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for xx.xxxxx.myapplication.PrefFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try replace in **OnCreateView**:

```
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
```

with:

```
if (rootView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
        }
        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_settings, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
        }
        return rootView;
```

Work fine and resolve this error:

**LOGCAT**

```
From the logcat: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f0e0052, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for xx.xxxxx.myapplication.PrefFragment
```